# I'm having trouble controlling an animated svg border using CSS

Tags: css, animation, svg

I've been trying to animate a svg border, I've gotten as far as this

```css
html {
  background: white;
}
div {
  position: fixed;
  height: 200px;
  width: 605px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 30%
}
.mainNav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 6;
}
[class="navBorder"] .outline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  stroke: #7272f8;
  stroke-width: 11px;
  fill: none;
}
.navBorder .outline {
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1900;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.navBorder:hover .outline {
  stroke-dasharray: 1100 0;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="navBorder" target="_blank">
    <svg height="100%" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <rect class="outline" height="100%" width="100%" />
    </svg>
  </a>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/lorehill/pen/pEPXar

The problem is I can't seem to get the starting position of the border to be on the top center and then close center bottom.

I'm very confused trying to figure out how to calculate the values I need to set stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset for the starting position in order to get the effect I'm after.

If anyone could explain it like I'm 5 that would be fantastic.

Thank you!

Comment: I'll give that a shot, thanks. I want it to go around both left and right evenly with the ends meeting in the middle. Do you think this can be achieved that way?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the starting position of the stroke is always the starting point of the rect which is top left for a `rect` element.

> I can't seem to get the starting position of the border to be on the top center and then close center bottom.

I think you'll need **two** polyline elements for that, although you can use the same class on both.

```css
svg {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em;
}
.outline {
  fill: lightblue;
  stroke-dasharray: 200;
  stroke-dashoffset: 190;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
svg:hover .outline {
  stroke-dasharray: 200 0;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 100 100">

  <polyline class="outline" points="50,0 100,0, 100,100 50,100" style="stroke:#660000; stroke-width: 3;" />

  <polyline class="outline" points="50,0 0,0 0,100 50,100" style="stroke:#660000; stroke-width: 3;" />

</svg>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ALrBVW)